# where are stored declared class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

In browser environment (for instance firefox 60+), I am trying to retrieve a class in the global window object, without success :

```
class c{};
console.log(window.c); // undefined
```

whereas for any other declaration

```
var foo = "bar";
console.log(window.foo); // bar
```

Where can I access declared class in the global object, for instance, if I need to create an instance from a class name stored in another variable.

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class

Comment: Store the classes in a `Map` or an object, not in the global window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
var Test = class {}
```